# How does network passphrase work?

Tags: private-network

I'm interested in creating a completely separate private network, and it seems like all I need to do is hide my `NETWORK_PASSPHRASE`. However, I'm not sure how that works exactly. i.e. when a new peer connects to my private network with my `NETWORK_PASSPHRASE`, where is it getting information about the peers on that network? How does it know what network it's talking to?

Answer (score 1):

The `NETWORK_PASSPHRASE` should be made public, because it permutes how transactions are hashed.  Since the passphrase determines the private key of the account containing the initial native tokens, however, you should obviously move those tokens to a different account before announcing your new network to other people.

If you want the technical details, have a look at `TransactionSignaturePayload` in [Stellar-transaction.x](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/src/xdr/Stellar-transaction.x).  You can see that any time a transaction hash or signature payload is computed, the computation involves a `networkId`, which is the SHA256 hash of the network passphrase.

Comment: I was wondering more about the technical aspects of how the passphrase is used. i.e. what a node armed with a specific `NETWORK_PASSPHRASE` does with it.